# gvim open dialog file type filter

Tags: vim, fileopendialog

I like using the file browser in gvim sometimes, however what I don't like is that the file filter is always set to the current file type being edited.

For example, if I have a .cpp file open in the current buffer and go to the file open dialog the file filter is set to "C++ source files (*.cpp *.c++)". I would prefer that headers are displayed too by default (say).

Is there a way to change this default behavior?

Comment: Are you talking about `:browse`?  If so, read `:help :browse`, especially the part about `browsefilter`.

Comment: @benjifisher: I totally missed that! That's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @benjifisher, I found the help for `:browse` which shows how to do what I wanted.
More specifically, the default filetype plugin for C/C++ contains these lines:

```
let b:browsefilter = "C++ Source Files (*.cpp *.c++)\t*.cpp;*.c++\n" .
 \ "C Header Files (*.h)\t*.h\n" .
 \ "C Source Files (*.c)\t*.c\n" .
 \ "All Files (*.*)\t*.*\n"
```

I copied the file into my local vim `ftplugin` directory and modified to my liking which now takes precedence over the system version.

Comment: I tried this in vim 7.4 (GTK2 version) in Ubuntu 14.04, but it does not work. I suspect it's not implemented. Any one has ideas?

Comment: @Mike I did this on debian so I strongly suspect it will work in ubuntu. To clarify what I did: I copied `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/c.vim` to `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim` and changed the appropriate `let b:browsefilter =...` line.

Comment: Thanks ozob, indeed, that works. I tried to add change the variable in ~/.vimrc, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone, like me, wants a quick and simple way to disable this behaviour altogether in vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType * let b:browsefilter = ''
```

[From first reply in this thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-do-I-turn-off-file-type-matching-in-open-file-dialog-td4828272.html)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, not anymore at least. I had to use `autocmd FileType * let b:browsefilter = 'All Files\t*\n'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I solved without having to copy the c.vim file to `~/.vim/ftplugin`. To support *.cc as a C++ extension, in GVim on Ubuntu I edited the `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/c.vim` file to add the extension:

`let b:browsefilter = "C++ Source Files (*.cpp *.c++ *cc)\t*.cpp;*.c++;*.cc\n" .
   \ "C Header Files (*.h)\t*.h\n" .
   \ "C Source Files (*.c)\t*.c\n" .
   \ "All Files (*.*)\t*.*\n"`

Then restarted GVim and it worked without copying `c.vim`.

Comment: Bad idea. It will likely get overwritten the next time your Vim gets updated. Copying is the sane thing to do, or just create a `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim` that just sets this variable.

Comment: OK that's true and I didn't think of it, though I recorded the change I made in case I need to do it again. Thanks!